# Attempting To Set Hidden Attribute To Windows 10 Default Start Menu Folders

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

As the title says, I'm trying to set the hidden attribute to ALL of the default folders found in the start menu.  There are two locations that these folders can be found in; appdata and programdata.  Here is the bat file that I first attempted:

```
takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" > NUL 2>&1

takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
takeown /f "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" /r /d y > NUL 2>&1
icacls "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" /grant administrators:F /t > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Accessories" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell" > NUL 2>&1
attrib +H "%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows System" > NUL 2>&1
```

I verified that takeown and icacls are returning successfully, but the ONLY folder this works on is the Maintenance folder from both the programdata and appdata locations. The rest of the folders not only persist, but if I try to delete them via explorer I receive a pop up saying I need admin access, click ok and it deletes. So obviously something is preventing or retaking ownership of the folders??

I then attempted via powershell using the following code:

```
(Get-Item "Folder Path").Attributes = 'Hidden'
```

When I use this code it works successfully on the Maintenance folder, but any of the others error out saying that the directory doesn't exist. What am I missing here? The account is an admin with UAC disabled and the bat file uses an auto-elevation to run as administrator, so I know that rights are fine.  I am open to cmd/powershell or even a 3rd party program if I can run it portable.

Comment: You are hiding all messages. You are doing something stupid.

Comment: "I verified that takeown and icacls are returning successfully" meaning I have done this without hiding and to no avail.  Please read next time.

Comment: Do you have sufficient access privileges? What about using `/S` option of `attrib` command?

Comment: `> NUL 2>&1` is hiding the output of every command.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250 is the way to do what you are doing. No code needed.

Comment: Noodles, did you not read my first response? "I have done this without hiding" would mean that I ran the code without > NUL 2>&1 already.  Please READ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for whatever reason, when viewing in explorer those folders are named as I have them in my bat file.  If I open cmd and go into the directory and get the listing, the folders have a different name.  I have changed my bat file to match the folder names found through cmd and everything works as it should.  Now I'm left with 2 unimportant questions:

1. Why did the takeown and icacls return as successful for folders that aren't there?
2. Does it have to do with those folders being linked together, like a library maybe?

Comment: They didn't. You are HIDING all output.

Comment: On every line you have this `> NUL 2>&1`. You were told you were hiding all output. You say it says its working. You are lying.

Comment: You are both idiots.  If someone says they verified the code as working, meaning not outputing an error, how would one do that in my code?  The ONLY way you can do this is by removing the nul portion at the end of all codes.  So, LOGICALLY that would mean that I did this.  Again, I followed up my own question with the ANSWER that proves I'm right.  As stated already multiple times, the code was verified to be working.  

Please, learn to read before running your mouth.